# IdentityServer4 -How can I add clientId and clientSecret to services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer project and API. I get JWT Token from IdentityServer to send requests to my API.

In my API, I don't use clientId and clientSecret anywhere. I don't understand why???

When I researched, API's Program.cs is used like this by many people;

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
   options.Authority = "[identity server url]";
   options.Audience = "[api resourse name]";
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

what I don't understand is, there is no clientId and clientSecret here.

Some people use [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation] to do what I wanted by using [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation);

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";
    options.ApiName = "api1";
    options.ApiSecret = "secret";
});
```

But when I tried this, my api doesn't return 401 Unauthorized and returns 200 OK even though my clientSecret is not correct.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Is your client secret being set in your Config.cs file in IdentityServer? I've used OIDC as middleware without any issues.

Comment: I set client secret in Config.cs, but I don't need any OIDC because I use API project. You are right about OIDC works well with a web app but I had a problem with API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AddJwtBearer authentication handler that you use in the API doesn't need a clientid/secret because all it needs to do is to accept and validate incoming access tokens using the public key that it downloads from the IdentityServer discovery document.

I think the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation is mainly useful if you need to support both JWT and reference tokens. But usually you only need JWT tokens.